# What does rhs stands for in Eigen?

Tags: eigen, eigen3

I am looking at the source of Eigen library, and saw a function named `gemm_pack_rhs`. Does anybody know what does this function do? And I saw a lot of place mentioning `rhs`. What does it mean in Eigen library?

Comment: I don't know about he specific function but it's usually right-hand-side and is commonly used for binary operators.

Comment: Thanks @patatahooligan, I think you are right :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To complete patatahooligan's answer, the `gemm_pack_rhs` function is used internally within matrix-matrix products to copy some blocks of the right-hand-side to a special memory layout suitable for efficient SIMD computations. There is an analogue function for the left-hand-side.